# Atribuir valor de CSS a um HTML através de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Criei este [*FIDDLE*](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lghrq22/) para verificar se o que estava a fazer, estava correcto ou errado. Aparentemente está errado:

O meu objectivo aqui é no **JavaScript** atribuir valores de **CSS** a um elemento de **HTML**, neste caso o valor `top`.

Basiei-me na resposta deste [problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737466/css-set-div-top-with-jquery-from-div-height) que encontrei, mas mesmo não tenho o resultado final pretendido que era por a `div` `100px` mais abaixo.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var altura = 100;

$("#footer").css("top", altura + "px");
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "footer">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: É isto que queres? -> http://jsfiddle.net/1Lghrq22/1/ nesse caso faltou só o `position: relative;` por exemplo

Comment: é exactamente isso que quero. Obrigado

Comment: @Sergio já agora.. e se eu quiser adicionar mais do que um parametro? como é que faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você trabalhar com posições de elementos, TOP, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM você DEVE usar a propriedade **Position**, com valores Relative, Absolute, Fixed...

Caso contrário você pode usar o **Margin-Top**, com valor de 100px.

Mude seu CSS para:

```
#footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
    position:relative; // Note aqui a propriedade Position
}
```

Comment: porque é que se eu passar o `position: relative` para `position: fixed` a `div desaparece`  jsfiddle.net/1Lghrq22/1

Comment: Porquê você tem que definir um tamanho **width** para os elementos.

Answer (score 1):

msm.oliveira, vi nos comentários que você gostaria de passar mais parâmetros.
Segue o código como exemplo com mais de um parâmetro.

```
$('elemento').css({ 'atributo':'Valor', 'atributo':'Valor', 'atributo':'Valor', });
```

ou para uma melhor leitura de código:

```
$('elemento').css({
    'atributo':'Valor',
    'atributo':'Valor',
    'atributo':'Valor',
});
```

Note que agora os pares atributo/valor devem estar entre apóstrofos ou entre aspas, e devem ser separados por :(dois pontos) e não mais por virgulas, a virgula agora é utilizada para separa os atributos que você deseja manipular.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando `Javascript` puro, caso não queira/possa utilizar jquery:

```
var elemento = document.querySelector("#teste");
elemento.style.backgroundColor = "#D93600";
```